# pandas concat with axis=1 returns unexpected shape

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate two dataframes with different columns for one-hot-encoding implementation. 
So I have the newly created dataframe which called 'df_train_cat' and the original training data called 'train'.

I tried:

```
print(train.shape)
print(df_train_cat.shape)
```

And got:

```
>> (4994, 30)
>> (4994, 17)
```

Which seems fine. 
But I can't understand the following line output:

```
print(pd.concat([train,df_train_cat],axis=1).shape)
>> (8702, 47)
```

I can't really figure out what actually happened... I was expecting the shape to be -

```
>> (4994,47)
```

My goal is pretty obvious -  create train and test dataframes with the new one-hot-encoding features.

```
train_new = pd.concat([train,df_train_cat], axis=1)
test_new = pd.concat([test, df_test_cat],  axis=1)
```

Comment: Index is not the same , pd.concat([train.reset_index(),df_train_cat.reset_index()],axis=1)

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

bd_test = pd.read_csv(r"D:\Dinesh\P1Data\Consumer_Complaints_test_share.csv")

bd_train = pd.read_csv(r"D:\Dinesh\P1Data\Consumer_Complaints_train.csv")

bd_train['data'] = 'train'

bd_test['data'] = 'test'

bd_test=bd_test[bd_train.columns]

## the columns in the two data frames should

#be in the same order to enable concatenation
#Consumer disputed?

bd_all=pd.concat([bd_train,bd_test],axis=1)

bd_all.shape